# Question about the ring $A_P$ of regular functions on a variety $V$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

***Note:** I am doing an introductory course in Commutative Algebra and not Algebraic Geometry; This is just a quick application I am trying to understand. Also, rings are commutative with $1$.*

When discussing localizations $S^{-1}A$ for a ring $A$ and $S\subset A$, we made the following example.

> **Def.** Let $k$ be a field, and $P$ be a prime ideal in $A=k[X_1,\dots, X_n]$. Let $V=\{(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in k^n:f(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0, \forall f\in P\}$ be the variety of $P$, and let $S=A\setminus P$.

Then $S^{-1}A$ is denoted $A_P$, and we have $A_P=\{\dfrac{f}{g}:f\in A,g\not\in P\}$. In class, this was called the ring of regular functions on $V$ (**EDIT**: *I learned this is apparently not how the ring of regular functions on V is defined, see the comments*). These are apparently well defined rational functions $k^n\to k$ since $g$ does not vanish on $V$, i.e. it seems we have

$g\not\in P\Rightarrow g(a_1,\dots a_n)\not =0$ for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in V$.

But, I think it's also evident that we have

$g\in P\Rightarrow g(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$ for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in V$

which is logically equivalent to $(g\not\in P) \vee (g(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$ for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in V)$.

It just feels like I'm missing something obvious, since I can't seem to deduce a contradiction from $g\not\in P$, and $g(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$ for some point of $V$.

**Question:** Why couldn't we have $g\not\in P$, but still have $g(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$, for some $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in V$?

Comment: This is not how I (or a number of others) would define the ring of regular functions on $V = V(\mathfrak{P}).$ I would call $k[V] :=A/\mathfrak{P}$ the ring of regular functions, and if $p = (a_1,\dots, a_n)\in V$ is a point on your variety, I would call $k[V]_{\mathfrak{m}_p}$ the ring of regular functions *at $p$* ($\mathfrak{m}_p$ is the maximal ideal of functions vanishing at the point $p$). These are the functions which do not vanish in some [unspecified] neighborhood around $p.$

Comment: Notice that $k[V]$ also consists of well defined functions on $V,$ as if $p\in V$ and $f$ and $g$ represent the same element of $k[V],$ then $f - g\in\mathfrak{P},$ so that $f(p) - g(p) = 0.$

Comment: As others have said $A_P$ is not really the ring of regular functions on $V$. Rather, it is the ring of rational functions on affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ that are regular on the subvariety $V$.

Comment: Ok, this was just what it was explicitly called by the professor, but I also guess he may have been a bit informal and quick there, since it was just an example. I edited in a comment about this into my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We absolutely can have $g\notin P$ and $g(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$ for some $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in V$.

Take $n=2$ and the prime ideal $P=(x)\subset k[x,y]$, so that $V=\{(a,b)\in k^2\mid a=0\}$. The function $g=y$ will vanish at the point $(0,0)\in V$, but it will not vanish at any other point $(0,b)$ with $b\neq0$.

Comment: I think I got a bit confused by a statement in the lectures sayin "If $g\not\in P$, then $g$ is non-vanishing on V". So, that is incorrect I suppose? Can we technically even have $g(a)=0$, for all $a\in V$ then?

Comment: @Christopher.L You would typically say $g$ is "vanishing on $V$" whenever $g(a)=0$ for all points $a\in V$, which is by definition if and only if $g\in P$. Your professor probably then meant by "non-vanishing" that $g$ does not vanish on at least one point of $V$.

Comment: Ok, but perhaps Im misunderstanding something: As I've defined V above, I only say that $g\in P$ implies $g(a)=0$ for all $a\in V$, right? I dont say the converse. So, as I said, it feels we could have g vanishing on V.

Comment: @Christopher.L yes you are right, the converse is not obvious a priori. However, this is actually true, and will likely be proved soon in your class as a theorem (sometimes called the Nullstellensatz).

Comment: Ah, ok, I've only heard the name of the theorem, have not gotten there yet; but I think I understand it better. And perhaps the professor took a little bit too much for granted since it was however just a quick application.